# Building iOS sticker app but new stickers aren't showing up in the app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-stickers

Built a sticker app for my friends and I to use. It's been in the App Store since November. Late November we added some new stickers and submitted to the App Store again (an update to the original app). So we have sticker sets A and B.

Recently we came up with more stickers to add, call them set C. I add the stickers to the app in Xcode like I've done previously but now 2 things happen. 1. I get an error from when trying to upload to the App Store ("The binary you uploaded was invalid") and 2. when I build and run the app on simulators only set A is in the app, while set B and C are missing.

For sticker apps in Xcode there isn't much code so debugging this is a pain in the, well you know. I have dug into the project and checked the Contents.json files for the assets and everything seems to be in there correctly. I don't know what else to check.

Also, I did a clean on the project thinking it might be related to the issue. Now when I try to install the app on a simulator it build then says "This app could not be installed at this time." Below is the line in the CoreSimulator.log

```
Jan 22 16:12:54 Koufax com.apple.dt.Xcode[8417] <Error>: installApplication:withOptions:error:: Error Domain=IXUserPresentableErrorDomain Code=1 "This app could not be installed at this time." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=This app could not be installed at this time., NSUnderlyingError=0x7facf460e550 {Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=122 "The messages stub app com.fostermatt.Ephsticks must have at least one app extension, but none were found." UserInfo={LegacyErrorString=MessagesStubAppMissingAppExtension, FunctionName=-[MIBundle validatePluginMetadataWithError:], SourceFileLine=478, NSLocalizedDescription=The messages stub app com.fostermatt.Ephsticks must have at least one app extension, but none were found.}}}
```

No clue how to get this working properly. Can anyone help?

Edit: Yes I know the log says "The messages stub app com.fostermatt.Ephsticks must have at least one app extension, but none were found." but being an iOS sticker app this should be done automatically by Xcode so I have no idea why it's not.

Comment: "The messages stub app com.fostermatt.Ephsticks must have at least one app extension, but none were found."

Answer (score 0):

Not really a solve but I got around the issue by just creating a completely new project and just naming it the original projects name. Updated the version and build numbers, put the correct icons and assets in the bundle, and then just built like new. Worked fine but I don't like the idea of just abandoning the previous project. Either way it works now and the updated app has been submitted for review.